# Error importing sensor_msgs/JointState

Tags: ros-melodic, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to run ROS on windows and to do that i followed this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows
I created a shortcut for Ros Command window from step 6 of the tutorial and than opened the window to test come code.
while testing I got error during importing of python package.

```
>>> from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named msg
```

but when importing just sensor_msg it works fine

After further looking into the problem location of the package I found was

```
>>> import sensor_msgs
>>> import os
>>> print(sensor_msgs.__file__)
C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\site-packages\sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg\sensor_msgs\__init__.py
```

And at this location there was a folder named as sensor_msgs and a file sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg

sensor_msgs folder did have msg package

```
dir C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\site-packages\sensor_msgs\msg
 _JointState.py
 _JointState.pyc
```

but was absent inside sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg

How can I import JointState when python is accessing sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg which does not have JointState instead of sensor_msgs folder which has one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347925/error-importing-sensor_msgs/jointstate/) by [abdullahsorathia](https://answers.ros.org/users/53031/abdullahsorathia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
This seems rather similar to [ms-iot/ROSOnWindows#202](https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/202).

Also:

> How can I import JointState when python is accessing sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg which does not have JointState instead of sensor_msgs folder which has one?

that's not really how Python works. I don't believe what you write there is the cause.

**Comment by [abdullahsorathia](https://answers.ros.org/users/53031/abdullahsorathia/) on 2020-03-31**:
yes it is the same issue not able to import sensor_msgs.msg

**Comment by [void32](https://answers.ros.org/users/21642/void32/) on 2020-03-31**:
sensor_msgs from sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg  does not match the content of C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\site-packages\sensor_msgs

Try

```
import sensor_msgs
print(dir(sensor_msgs))
```

You will see that sensor_msgs are missing msg

A quick fix could be to make a new sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg from C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\site-packages\sensor_msgs or import from the folder directly.

**Comment by [abdullahsorathia](https://answers.ros.org/users/53031/abdullahsorathia/) on 2020-03-31**:
Thank you, I was able to make it work by taking backup and replacing sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg with the new sensor_msgs-1.12.7-py2.7.egg made from the content of C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\site-packages\sensor_msgs folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone else coming here, this is the latest comment by @OoeyGUI on [ms-iot/ROSOnWindows#202](https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/202):

> We are preparing an updated release.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0